# Sod shock tube - Contact Discontinuity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, ideal-gas, superfluidity, shock-waves

sorry for bothering with my question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod_shock_tube

I have trying to understand, how is it possible to have a discontinuity on Density and not on Pressure. I don't understand, since we have a Pressure AND a Density discontinuity on t=0 , how can the equilibrium of the Pressure take place Immediate? I understand the Shock the rarefaction but the contact discontinuity bothers me a lot for some days and can't find anything related on Google.

Probably it's a stupid question, but still.. didn't know any other place to ask

Comment: I think there is a typo in your expressions for pressure and density near the top.  Both currently have a subscript of 2.

Comment: Can you normalize the density and pressure plots to the ambient/upstream values or at least show them on a log-linear scale?  It's impossible to tell the relative strength of each density discontinuity from these plots.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I fixed it! I had some wrong plots. Is it clear now? It's clear that there are 2 discntinuities on density and one on pressure

Comment: This is often called the [Sod Shock Tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod_shock_tube), and [here are some good references](http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~tohline/PHYS7412/sod.html).  I can write a more complete answer later, but in short there is only one pressure discontinuity because there is only one surface traveling faster than the local speed of sound---thus preventing the discontinuity from smoothing out.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Sweat, I ll read them both. I still dont get the Discontinuity on density, but I ll study it more and hopefully I will